# Equivalent baseband communication channel

Tags: signal, communication, wireless, signal-processing, telecommunications

I was reading on my lecture slides (I do not put them here since they are not in English) this statement about equivalent baseband channel models:

> In typical wireless applications, communication occurs in a passband [fc W/2;
> fc
> +W/2]
> of bandwidth
> W around a center frequency
> fc. However, most of the processing, such as
> coding/decoding, modulation/demodulation, synchronization, etc., is actually done at the
> baseband. Therefore from a communication system design point of view, it is most useful
> to have a baseband equivalent representation of the system.
>
> [image]
>
> Since
>
> [image]
>
> it results:
>
> [image]
>
> and
>
> [image]
>
> and
>
> [image]

I do not understand what it wants to get and why. Precisely:

- what does it mean with "equivalent channel model"? I'd say that it means a channel with same input, same output, and same transfer function
- which is the equivalent baseband channel model between the last two pictures?
- So are baseband signal really used inside a channel?

Comment: Not very clear but appears to be copied from this book. https://books.google.ca/books?id=GdsLAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA22&lpg=PA22&dq=However,+most+of+the+processing,+such+as+coding/decoding,+modulation/demodulation,+synchronization&source=bl&ots=aLGt4dKQil&sig=ACfU3U2f0UkDE6nPOZEgTWHwHbMH8Qpa-g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwix8JX1zOfpAhXNmeAKHbfvClMQ6AEwAHoECC8QAQ#v=onepage&q=However%2C%20most%20of%20the%20processing%2C%20such%20as%20coding%2Fdecoding%2C%20modulation%2Fdemodulation%2C%20synchronization&f=false  They are showing fundamentals of quadrature encoder/decoder e.g. QPSK

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-shift_keying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For many cases where you have a passband signal (meaning, a signal with some carrier frequency, \$f_c\$, and a signal with bandwidth \$W\$ around it, typical in communications systems), analysis is more convenient working with the so-called *baseband equivalent* version of that signal. It is called baseband equivalent, because it takes out the dependence on \$f_c\$, and can be viewed as a sort of baseband signal that is equivalent to the passband signal in a way. In your example, in the frequency domain, the passband is \$S(f)\$ and the baseband equivalent is \$S_b(f)\$.

Similarly, if you pass the passband signal through a channel, then you'd need a baseband equivalent channel model, that you can pass the baseband equivalent signal through. The whole system is known as the *baseband equivalent representation of the system* (that is referenced in the quotation you provided).

What is the baseband equivalent of the passband signal? Your example shows a baseband equivalent signal, \$s(t)\$ being derived. Notice that it is no longer real-valued, but complex valued in general. However, it is not a function of \$f_c\$ anymore, which helps with analysis. At the output of the system, you can always convert back to passband if desired.